# How to unhighlight a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlighting

I wrote a function to highlight a text which is selected using following method,

```
$('.highlight').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<span style=background-color:yellow;>"+ document.getSelection()+"</span>");
    });
```

but, now i needs to unhighlight the selected text, could you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) You should use the class instead of inline styles. Then you can simply remove the class to unhighlight.

Comment: Does the HTML exist before this function is run?

Comment: @amflare we can highlight a text which is displaying on a div tag

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.highlighted{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

JS

```
    $('.highlight').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<span class='selectedText highlighted'>"+ document.getSelection()+"</span>");
    });

    // CALL THIS FUNCTION, WHEN YOU NEED TO UNHIGHLIGHT
    function unhighlight(){
        $(".selectedText").removeClass("highlighted");
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to get background color of selected text